# "Ambiguous use of subscript" Error after new Swift update

Tags: ios, json, swift

My project was running fine before and still runs fine if using the simulator.  But when I connect an iPhone and try and run the project I get this error: "Ambiguous use of subscript" when retrieving JSON info on this line:

```
 let channels = jsonResult["channels"]?[0] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Any help to remedy this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler seems to be more type restrictive.

The result type of `jsonResult["channels"]` is `AnyObject` you have to help the compiler by checking the value for being an array.

```
if let channels = jsonResult["channels"] as? [AnyObject], channel = channels[0] as? [String: AnyObject] {
  // do something with channel
}
```

Or still safer to check also whether the array is not empty

```
if let channels = jsonResult["channels"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] where !channels.isEmpty {
   let channel = channels[0] // now the compiler knows it's [String:AnyObject]
   // do something with channel
}
```