# Ambiguous Use of Subscript (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, subscript

I am using the subscript in the following code incorrectly for this Firebase data pull, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I get an error of Ambiguous use of subscript for the `let uniqueID = each.value["Unique ID Event Number"] as! Int` line.

```
// Log user in
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

       let uid = user.uid
       // values for vars sevenDaysAgo and oneDayAgo set here

       ...

       let historyRef = self.ref.child("historyForFeedbackLoop/\(uid)")
            historyRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "Unix Date").queryStarting(atValue: sevenDaysAgo).queryEnding(atValue: oneDayAgo).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
                    print("user data not found")
                }
                else {

                    if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                        for each in snapDict {

                            // Save the IDs to array.
                            let uniqueID = each.value["Unique ID Event Number"] as! Int
                            self.arrayOfUserSearchHistoryIDs.append(uniqueID)
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        print("SnapDict is null")
                    }
                }
       })
}
```

I tried to applying what I learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642059/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-in-swift), but I couldn't figure out what I am missing because I thought I was letting the compiler know what type of dictionary it is with the "as? [String:AnyObject]"

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred way of dealing with data is to unwrap the `FIRDataSnapshot` as late as possible.

```
ref!.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let msg = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
        print("\(msg.key): \(msg.value!)")
        let val = msg.value! as! [String:Any]
        print("\(val["name"]!): \(val["message"]!)")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that spark of an idea.  Worked like a charm once I re-worked it in this manner.  Will respond as an answer separately so others can see if they run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Frank's feedback into account, here is the actual working code I used that follows that approach in case it's helpful.

```
// Log user in
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

   let uid = user.uid
   // values for vars sevenDaysAgo and oneDayAgo set here

   ...

   let historyRef = self.ref.child("historyForFeedbackLoop/\(uid)")
        historyRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "Unix Date").queryStarting(atValue: sevenDaysAgo).queryEnding(atValue: oneDayAgo).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
                print("user data not found")
            }
            else {

                 for child in snapshot.children {

                    let data = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                    let value = data.value! as! [String:Any]
                    self.arrayOfUserSearchHistoryIDs.append(value["Unique ID Event Number"] as! Int)
                 }
            }
   })
}
```